# Why isn't my docker finding certificate store when running Java? What should I add to the docker creation or invocation?

Tags: java, docker, webserver, keystore

I have a web application written in Java and running on a host. It runs fine, using spark (model and view, service, velocity, and of course ignite). I am trying to put the application in a docker image based on `amazoncorretto:8`, but when it runs on the same host, it tells me `java.lang.IllegalStateException: no valid keystore`.

According to the documentation, Corretto does have a store (`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto/jre/lib/security/cacerts`)

I tried adding these lines to the `Dockerfile` (because this is how it looks on the host):
`RUN mkdir -p /etc/ssl/certs`
`COPY di.* /etc/ssl/certs` (di.* are the key and crt that I'm using)
But this doesn't help. Does it mean I have to create a keystore? Can I map an external `/etc/ssl/certs` folder to the docker? Will it help?

Comment: Thank you. But can you help me understand what I need to do?

Comment: `cacerts` is a truststore, not a key store, and a directory is not a key store either.